# ERROR:- as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, python-3.x

After running the server i am getting error as as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given please have a look on below code and suggest me.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
    import json
    class JsonCBV(View):
        def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
                emp_data= 
                {'eno':100,'ename':'pankhu','esal':300000,'eaddr':'pune'}
                return JsonResponse(emp_data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from testapp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('jsonapi3/', views.JsonCBV.as_view),
                 ]
```

test.py

```
import requests
    BASE_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    ENDPOINT='jsonapi3'
    resp =requests.get(BASE_URL+ENDPOINT)
    data=resp.json()
    print('Data from django application')
    print('#'*50)
    print('Employee number:',data['eno'])
    print('Employee name:',data['ename'])
    print('Employee salary:',data['esal'])
    print('Employee address:',data['eaddr'])
```

Comment: In the urls.py try giving `path('jsonapi3/', views.JsonCBV.as_view()),` instead of `path('jsonapi3/', views.JsonCBV.as_view),`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

in your urls you have to write parentheses after `.as_view()`

```
path('jsonapi3/', views.JsonCBV.as_view())
```